# angular not displaying object attributes

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am following the [HeroTutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) but using a Django backend. I have an `Hero` object that I am getting from DRF endpoint (verified with Postman). In my **hero-detail.html** the `hero.name` and `hero.id` are not displaying anything.

I know the `hero` object is being passed to the **hero-detail.html** because the browser shows the "Details" and "id:" so the line `<div *ngIf="hero">` is telling me that there is a `hero`..

But if there is a `hero` why does `hero.name` not show anything?

There are no errors in the browser console. The link to get to the **hero-detail.component** is coming from a **dashboard.component** which uses the same method but for some reason `hero.name` and `hero.number` work fine. The **dashboard.component.html** displays correctly so I know my services are working fine.

My **hero-detail.html**

```
<div *ngIf="hero">

<h2>{{hero.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{hero.number}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name:
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </label>
</div>

</div>

<button (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
```

**hero-detail.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { HeroService }  from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.scss']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private heroService: HeroService,
  private location: Location
) {}

  @Input() hero: Hero;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHero();
  }

  getHero(): void {
    const number = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('number');
    this.heroService.getHero(number)
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }

  goBack(): void {
  this.location.back();
}

  }
```

**dashboard.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.scss' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<h3>Top Heroes</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="col-1-4"
      routerLink="/detail/{{hero.number}}">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h1>{{hero.name}}</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**hero.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class HeroService {

private heroesUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/heroes/';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
  private http : HttpClient
) { }

  /**
 * Handle Http operation that failed.
 * Let the app continue.
 * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
 * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
 */

  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)

}

  getHero(number:number): Observable<Hero>{
    return this.http.get<Hero>(`${this.heroesUrl}${number}`);
  }

//  getHero(number: number): Observable<Hero> {
//  return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.number === number));
//}


}
```

**hero.service** endpoint response from `localhost:8000/heroes/2`, taken from Postman:

```
[
    {
        "name": "better hero",
        "number": 2
    }
]
```

also **hero.service** endpoint response from `localhost:8000/heroes`, taken from Postman:

```
[
    {
        "name": "bad hero",
        "number": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "bad hero",
        "number": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "better hero",
        "number": 2
    }
]
```

**views.py**

```
class HeroList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Hero.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HeroSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('number', 'name')


class HeroDetail(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = HeroSerializer

 #TODO why do i need many=True here, this should returning one instance
    def get(self, request, number):
        # number = self.request.query_params.get('number')
        hero_detail = Hero.objects.filter(number=number)
        serializer = HeroSerializer(hero_detail, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('number', 'name')
```

Comment: you have posted the hero-details components twice instead of the dashboard, please edit the question :) also it is not clear why you have a hero Input in hero-details, because you are getting the hero from the service (getting the id from url and passing to the service) so looks like you should make hero a class variable and not input

Comment: Can you post the sample response from /heroes/ and /heroes/id services?

Comment: @Shaniqwa - Thanks for pointing that out, updated. i came across the same thought about the @Input question but didnt think it was relevant to this problem. I also included what is coming from the DRF for a specific `hero` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sample API responses you've posted, it looks like retrieve method for a hero (/heroes/2 for instance) returns a list with only one item, instead of returning the item itself. In your client code though, you expect a hero object, not a hero list. Depending on your client code and for a rest api in general,

localhost:8000/heroes/2 should return

```
{
    "name": "better hero",
    "number": 2
}
```

not

```
[
    {
        "name": "better hero",
        "number": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: ah! this makes sense thats why this only works if I set `many=True` in my Djano view... I still am not sure where the error is tho. I added my django views.py it should be just the instance that is returned.. maybe the `filter` always returns a list?

Comment: In your HeroDetail view, you need to change hero_detail = Hero.objects.filter(number=number) to hero_detail = Hero.objects.get(number=number). When you use filter, you get back a queryset, that's why you need to use many=True in that case. When you use get, you get back a single instance

Comment: I swear i tried that earlier, must have done something wrong. Now i am getting `ross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response`.. but as far as the original question I think you nailed it, thanks so much!!!